# Android: How do I register applications that are not running, with a service?

Tags: android

Background: Android provides a nice method of backing up data. To have the data of an application backed up whenever a system-wide backup is performed, an application should have  a backup agent specified as an attribute of it's application tag, in the applications manifest.

```
<application android:label="MyApplication"
         android:backupAgent="MyBackupAgent">
```

Question: I would like to use a similar mechanism for a file retrieval service I am creating. My question is, how does one programatically scan for applications with a given attribute in their application tag, and launch the object associated with that attribute? Is this possible?

Note that the target application may not necessarily be running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. After looking into the Android source I see that it is not possible to extend the attributes of standard tags. Instead, meta-data can be used to achieve a similar result.

The solution I devised was to include a meta-data tag in applications that I want 'registered' with my service. For example:

AndroidManifest.xml (of target application(s))

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <meta-data android:name="MyAttribute" android:value="myvalue" />
```

The service I developed scans the installed packages to find those with the relevant meta-data:

```
List<PackageInfo> packages = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for (int a = packages.size();-1; a >= 0; a--) { 
    PackageInfo pkg = packages.get(a);       
    ApplicationInfo ai = packages.get(a).pkg.applicationInfo;
    boolean remove = true;
    if (ai.metaData != null && ai.metaData.get("LogRetrievalAgent") != null) {
    remove = ai.metaData.get("LogRetrievalAgent").toString().compareTo("test") != 0;
    }

    if (remove) {
        packages.remove(pkg);
    }
}
```