# Is it possible to have custom attributes in AndroidManifest.xml tags?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I would like to add a custom attribute to the application tag of my AndroidManifest.xml file. Is this possible in the Android environment?

Comment: i guess not ...but can you elaborate this...

Comment: Sure, my motivations are here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10311504/183123. I would like to have an application register with a service I am developing. The target application need not be running

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes.  Here's an example.  The custom tag is `ContentVersion`.

```
<application android:name=".MyApplication"
             android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:label="@string/app_name">

    <meta-data android:name="ContentVersion" android:value="1.9" />

    <activity android:name="com.someone.something.MainActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
              android:screenOrientation="sensor"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
```

To access it:

```
    ApplicationInfo ai = _context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(_context.getPackageName(),PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    ai.metaData.get("ContentVersion")
```

Comment: Huh.  A downvote with no comment.  That doesn't help!  Please tell me what is wrong with my answer, if you ever come back!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972963/add-android-metadata-tag-in-theme-apk-and-read-the-value can you suggest me

Comment: It appears that you can't add <meta-data> to an <application> tag. Here's the relevant doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html

Comment: @JoeBowers Thanks for that.  Interesting!  However, it does work, and continues to work in published apps so presumably under all later versions.   I will test again though.

Comment: @JoeBowers The documentation seems to be wrong. If I put that tag in a `<service>` it doesn't work (`metaData` is `null`), but when it is in `<application>` it works fine.

Comment: OK, 2 downvotes now on a perfectly good answer.  I'm not in this for the points, and I really don't care about losing 2 of them, I've got thousands, so go ahead and downvote if you wish but PLEASE have the goodness to tell me why.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot define custom attribute to a predefined tag, but you can add key-value pairs called [meta-data](http://androiddevblog.blogspot.se/2010/07/using-android-application-meta-data.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could go for a [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), instead (aka, settings).

Comment: this is completely unrelated.

Comment: Not completely. I was going for other solutions that could fit in this situation.

Comment: tags in the manifest are added at compile time and accessed at runtime. sharedpreferences are created and accessed at runtime.

Comment: @njzk2 manifest is accessed even before runtime of your app to e.g. install the app.

Comment: Well, it's ok to me then. He was not clear enough to ensure any of our (both yours and mine) supposition.

Comment: @zapl : by the system, yes. but you can access it during the runtime of your app

Answer (score 0):

In the  tag (as well as service and receiver), you can use the  tag (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html )

It contains a name and a value or a resource ID.

You retrieve it through the PackageManager.

Answer (score -2):

If anybody needs that for Xamarin (Mono for Android) I couldn't find the constant, but i found the value for it, which is 128.

I used a "for" condition to go through all values from 0 to 1000 and check whenever the MetaData property was not null. lol