# Setting parameters for activities / services

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

Is there a way to set parameters that they would receive as arguments in the constructor were they initialized as standard objects instead of by intents? I can't use parameters stored in the intent because sending an intent doesn't necessarily initialize the activity / service (it may exist already). Can I use the manifest file to set custom parameters?
Thanks.

Comment: quite vague to understand, could you please post a sample that demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Ok, my specific problem is that I have a bound service and I want it to be able to use any Executor to serve the clients, so that it will be able to handle the requests sequentially if given an Executor that uses only 1 thread, and also using a thread pool if supplied a ThreadPoolExecutor. I don't want the binding activities to be responsible for setting the Executor, but want it configured somehow. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible solution here: [Is it possible to have custom attributes in AndroidManifest.xml tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311890/is-it-possible-to-have-custom-attributes-in-androidmanifest-xml-tags)
Doesn't help if I want to pass objects, but for simple types it's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Starting an Activity will always start activity, and if activity is already in stack, then also it would launch the activity, unless some intent filter havent been specified.

For Service, if you start service by startService(), onStartCommand() method will be invoked, which has an Intent as parameter, you can get values passed from this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> sending an intent doesn't necessarily initialize the activity / service(it may exist already).

What if you keep using Intents but erase the history of the TargetActivity each time you call it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,TargetActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```