# Add android metadata tag in theme apk and read the value

Tags: android, themes

Add android metadata tag in theme apk and read the value,
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311890/is-it-possible-to-have-custom-attributes-in-androidmanifest-xml-tags) and for application apk it works fine but I have theme apk it doesn't has `application` tag , I tried adding metadata under `manifest` tag but its not working. can some one help me in adding how metadata or custom tag in manifest and retrive its value in android application using packagemanager

The manifest of my theme apk is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest android:hasCode="false" android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="internalOnly" package="com.template.theme.y"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:pluto="http://www.w3.org/2001/pluto.html">
    <theme pluto:wallpaperImage="@drawable/wallpaper" pluto:ringtoneFileName="media/audio/ringtones/Standard.mp3" pluto:preview="@drawable/preview" pluto:styleName="@string/style_appearance_name" pluto:ringtoneName="Standard" pluto:name="@string/theme_name" pluto:author="@string/author" pluto:notificationRingtoneName="Subtle" pluto:themeId="Templatebread" pluto:notificationRingtoneFileName="media/audio/notifications/Subtle.mp3" pluto:styleId="@style/Templatebread" pluto:copyright="@string/copyright">
        <meta-data android:name="themeEngineVersion" android:value="101" />
    </theme>
</manifest>
```